# Spring - How to pass a message between Views?

Tags: java, spring, controller

I have an application that displays, edits and deletes Accounts.

1. **Display** uses `displayAccounts.jsp` and is invoked by `/accounts` url
2. **Edit** uses `editAccount.jsp` and is invoked by `/accounts/{id}/edit` where `id` is the Primary Key to the Account to be edited.
3. **Delete** does not have a view of it's own, but simply calls the `@RequestMapping` method in the Controller, and is invoked by `/accounts/{id}/delete`

Every action, on success, redirects to the Display page.

1. Once an operation (Edit/Delete) has been successfully performed, I want to send a success message that can be displayed on the Display page. How can I accomplish this?
2. Since I dont have a view for the Delete operation, I want to display the Errors in the Display page too.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your controller code snapshot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use of `RedirectAttributes` is what you need to achieve this. I assume that from the POST methods of EDIT and DELETE operation you are using "redirect:" to redirect to the DISPLAY view through its controller.

To achieve this you need to have `RedirectAttributes attributes` as a parameter in the controller function. Then before the return statement you should add following line of code.

```
attributes.addFlashAttribute("successMsg", "Account Edit/Delete successfully");
```

or

```
attributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMsg", "Edit/Delete account is unsuccessful");
```

in case of error message.

And then on the **displayAccounts.jsp** page you just need to display the message with `${successMsg}` or `${errorMsg}`

Once the message will be displayed and if you refresh the page then the message will not come up. It will be displayed to the user just once.

This is perfect for your scenario. Even I use this.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, @japs. You seemed to understand the problem very well. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your **EDIT** operation opens different view, then you can pass the message from Controller to the view using following

```
ModelAndView  mav = new ModelAndView();
```

and then set the message object as

```
mav.addObject("message", "EDIT sucessfully completed");
```

and in last, set the view name

```
mav.setViewName("views/afterEditOperation/");
```

You can use the message directly on your view as **${mesasage}**

Comment: Lemme try that out and let you know, @arun-kumar

Comment: @th3an0maly Sure. Please have a try.

Comment: Well, I got a simpler and more direct solution for my problem. Thanks for the help, anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

In Controller method in edit and delete method, write a message string into Model as

Edit

```
model.addAttribute("message", "Record Edited Sucessfully");
model.addAttribute("accountList", accountList);
```

Delete

```
model.addAttribute("accountList", accountList);
model.addAttribute("message", "Record Deleted Sucessfully");
```

and in your displayAccounts.jsp write code to display this message as

```
<div>
  <span>${message}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, the view `displayAccounts` will only contain the `result` attribute. It wont display the accounts unless I perform a `redirect`. Moreover, the way you propose, the link remains `/accounts/{id}/delete` and thereafter, even a Refresh wont populate my page with the Accounts to be displayed.

Comment: You can add multiple attributes in model, please check above updates answer. Please share your Controller Code Snapshot

Answer (score 1):

You can use **AJAX** in this case . With this, you can send your action from the same page to **Controller** for delete operation and get the message from controller on the same page to show sucesss/error message of delete operation from controller.

Comment: Is there any other method that doesn't involve Ajax? And what about my Edit operation, that happens in a separate view?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass some message (error/success) to display page from controller than may below code helps,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
public class editDeleteController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String methodName(ModelMap model) { 
        model.addAttribute("message", "Message1");
                model.addAttribute("moremessage", "Message2");
        return "viewName";//veiwName here in your case it is displayPage 
    }
}
```

In display page you will get it by,

```
<h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
```

Explain in details if this will not work for you.

Thank you

---

Okay I think i got your point do some think like this,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editDelete(ModelMap model) {

        if(success)
        {
            model.addAttribute("result", "Success");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/displaytagView");//Chaining your controller so it will refresh your Accounts
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("result", "Error");
                        return "displayPage";
        }
    }
```

Chaining controller to displayPage Controller so it shows refreshed data. Try this hope its work

Comment: The problem with this approach is, the view `displayAccounts` will only contain the `result` attribute. It wont display the accounts unless I perform a `redirect`. Moreover, the way you propose, the link remains `/accounts/{id}/delete` and thereafter, even a Refresh wont populate my page with the Accounts to be displayed.

Comment: i think i got your problem you can solve this using Chaining Controller. I have edited my answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @nishant-solanki. I got a more direct and straight-forward answer for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provide ModelMap type object, you can put your data in ModelMap type object.This object is accessible throughout the application. Here you can put a String type variable having value either Success or Failure (based on condition).Later on you can access this model object from jsp page.here is the example.

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/accounts/{id}/edit ")
 //  public String yourMethod(ModelMap model)
public String yourMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response,ModelMap model){
   if(someCondition){
     String result = "Success";
    model.addAttribute("result", result);
    }
      else{
          String result="failure";
          model.addAttribute("result", result);
        }
        // return "displayAccounts";
       return new YourControllerClass().yourMethodforAccountDisplay(request, response,model);//this is where you specify account display method with appropriate argument
   }
```

you can access result from jsp page as below -

```
         ${result}
```

Please enable viewresolver in Spring configuration file.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, the view `displayAccounts` will only contain the `result` attribute. It wont display the accounts unless I perform a `redirect`. Moreover, the way you propose, the link remains `/accounts/{id}/delete` and thereafter, even a Refresh wont populate my page with the Accounts to be displayed.

Comment: I have update the code .now you can call account display method form here. One more alternate is use forward instead of redirect.

Comment: Well, I got a simpler and more direct solution for my problem. Thanks for the help, anyways :)

Comment: You are welcome. I too have learned new things from your problem.